# adding custom parameters for highcharts using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to add some parameters to my highcharts that are being called by ajax. I call all the necessary parameters in a separate php, then the success result would put it in the container for highcharts.

My Code:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'sdayresult.php',
      data: $("#FormName").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {    
      //$("#anser").html(data);
      $('#container').highcharts({data});
       }
```

The value of the data:

```
 chart: {
            type: 'scatter'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Search by Airline'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['none']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '# of Crew'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '# of Crew',
            URLs: ['#'],
            data: [0],
           point: {
                events: {
                  click: function() {
                  var someURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.x]; // onclick get the x index and use it to find the URL
                  if (someURL)
                   window.open('http://'+someURL);
                }}}         
        }]
```

But when I run the script, the is a javascript error saying that I have an undefined "}". I tried pasting the value of the data to another test page of highcharts and it seems that the value of data is correct. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: did you included all required highcharts js library...?

Comment: If you have extra `}` then remove it. You have just error in JS, that's all.